# What does proto means, xdp/ebpf?

Tags: bpf, ebpf

What does proto signifies over here, I was following this
`https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/tree/master/tracing03-xdp-debug-print` Can anyone explain what proto means in this context?

```
$ sudo ./trace_read
src: 5a:b3:63:62:de:d7 dst: 3a:b:b:8e:5e:6a proto: 56710
src: 5a:b3:63:62:de:d7 dst: 3a:b:b:8e:5e:6a proto: 56710
src: 5a:b3:63:62:de:d7 dst: 3a:b:b:8e:5e:6a proto: 56710
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, given it seems to be displaying L2 information, `proto` is the [Ethertype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType). It indicates the protocol of the next header (L3).

56710 is 0xDD86 (in big endian) in hexadecimal, which corresponds to the Ethertype of IPv6.